# rewrite url for 2 or 3 "subfolders"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a working rewrite rule for 
domain.com/companyname

its a wildcard rule since i wont know whats in the position of "companyname". And rules to take care of urls that DO exist
So far so good

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule   ^(.*?)$/  profile/index.php?company=$1
```

But sometimes i might need to add an extra subfolder if a company has several departments line

domain.com/companyname/london/ or domain.com/companyname/berlin
The following rule will do that

```
    RewriteRule   ^(.*?)/(.*?)$  profile/index.php?company=$1&city=$2
```

But the problem is that the first rule will also catch the url with city subfolder.

How can i make both rules work ? i guess i need to make sure rule 1 only takes those with companyname and no city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have more specific rule first:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?)/?$ profile/index.php?company=$1&city=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ profile/index.php?company=$1 [L,QSA]
```